# undefined is not an object (evaluating '_expoFont.default.loadAsync')

Tags: react-native, expo

I've got this problem and did't find right answer.

```
undefined is not an object (evaluating '_expoFont.default.loadAsync')
* App.js:77:17 in _callee$
- node_modules/@babel/runtime/node_modules/regenerator-runtime/runtime.js:45:44 in tryCatch
- node_modules/@babel/runtime/node_modules/regenerator-runtime/runtime.js:271:30 in invoke
- node_modules/@babel/runtime/node_modules/regenerator-runtime/runtime.js:45:44 in tryCatch
- node_modules/@babel/runtime/node_modules/regenerator-runtime/runtime.js:135:28 in invoke
- node_modules/@babel/runtime/node_modules/regenerator-runtime/runtime.js:170:17 in <unknown>
- node_modules/promise/setimmediate/core.js:45:7 in tryCallTwo
- node_modules/promise/setimmediate/core.js:200:23 in doResolve
- node_modules/promise/setimmediate/core.js:66:12 in Promise
- node_modules/@babel/runtime/node_modules/regenerator-runtime/runtime.js:169:27 in callInvokeWithMethodAndArg
- node_modules/@babel/runtime/node_modules/regenerator-runtime/runtime.js:192:38 in enqueue
- node_modules/@babel/runtime/node_modules/regenerator-runtime/runtime.js:216:8 in async
* App.js:74:23 in _callee
- node_modules/expo/build/launch/AppLoading.js:13:22 in _callee$
- node_modules/@babel/runtime/node_modules/regenerator-runtime/runtime.js:45:44 in tryCatch
- ... 35 more stack frames from framework internals
```

This is exactly how it looks like:
[image]

Here's the App.js

> import { AppLoading } from 'expo';
>       import { Asset } from 'expo-asset'; 
>       import Font from 'expo-font'; 
>       import React from 'react'; 
>       import { Feather } from '@expo/vector-icons'; 
>       import { Block } from './components' 
>       import AppNavigator from './navigation/AppNavigator'; 
>       import MainTabNavigator from './navigation/MainTabNavigator';
>
> ```
>     // Firebase import ApiKeys from './constants/ApiKeys'; import * as firebase from 'firebase'
>
> const images = [   require('./assets/icons/back.png'),   require('./assets/images/illustration_1.png'),
> ```
>
> require('./assets/images/illustration_2.png'),
>   require('./assets/images/illustration_3.png'),
>   require('./assets/images/dealsBackground.png'), ];
>
> ```
> class App extends React.Component {
>      constructor(props) {
>     super(props);
>     this.state = {
>       isLoadingComplete: false,
>       isAuthenticationReady: false,
>       isAuthenticated: false,
>     };
>
>     // Initialize firebase...
>     if (!firebase.apps.length) { firebase.initializeApp(ApiKeys.firebaseConfig); }
>     firebase.auth().onAuthStateChanged(this.onAuthStateChanged);   }
>
>   onAuthStateChanged = (user) => {
>     this.setState({isAuthenticationReady: true});
>     this.setState({isAuthenticated: !!user});   }
>
>   render() {
>     if ( (!this.state.isLoadingComplete || !this.state.isAuthenticationReady) && !this.props.skipLoadingScreen) {
>       return (
>         <AppLoading
>           startAsync={this.loadResourcesAsync}
>           onError={this._handleLoadingError}
>           onFinish={this._handleFinishLoading}
>         />
>       );
>     } else {
>       return (
>           <Block white>
>             {(this.state.isAuthenticated) ? <MainTabNavigator /> : <AppNavigator />}
>           </Block>
>       );
>     }   }
>
>   loadResourcesAsync = async () => {
>     return Promise.all([
>       Asset.loadAsync(images),
>       await Font.loadAsync(Feather.font)
>     ]);   };
>
>   _handleLoadingError = error => {
>     // In this case, you might want to report the error to your error
>     // reporting service, for example Sentry
>     console.warn(error);   };
>
>   _handleFinishLoading = () => {
>     this.setState({ isLoadingComplete: true });   }; }
>
> export default App;
> ```

I think, I have no error in it and the app working fine.

## The correct answer is:

```
import * as Font from 'expo-font';
```

Comment: Can you post your `App.js` file please ? (including the imports)

Comment: I add App.js in the post.

Comment: [Read the docs](https://docs.expo.io/versions/latest/sdk/font/). Your import for expo-font is wrong.

Comment: Yes, that's right. Thanks @JJJ , Could you post your answer, Please? Because I want to choose it the correct answer.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

## The correct answer is import * as Font:

```
import * as Font from 'expo-font';
```